# Symfony Actions Namespacing, or a better way?

Tags: model-view-controller, namespaces, symfony1, action

In Rails, you can organize controllers into folders and keep your structure nice with namespacing.  I'm looking for a similar organizational structure in Symfony 1.4.

I was thinking of organizing multiple actions.class.php files in an actions folder, but all I came across was using independent action files, one for each action... like this:

```
# fooAction.class.php
class fooAction extends sfActions {
  public function executeFoo() {
    echo 'foo!';
  }
}
```

But I'd have to develop a whole new routing system in order to fit multiple actions into that file, which is... silly.

Really I'm just looking to make Symfony into Rails, (again, silly, but I'm stuck with Symfony for this project) so I'm wondering if there's a better way....?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve - as in, why you need this in Symfony. Can you explain further? :-)

Comment: I'm trying to group actions into sets with their own files, for organizational purposes.  The actions file is going to get huge otherwise.  I _would_ put them in their own modules, and that'd be fine, except then I'd pollute the modules folder with a billion modules.  What I'm really looking for is a directory structure like this: apps/frontend/modules/GROUP/module1, apps/frontend/modules/GROUP/module1.  But I haven't found a way to do that.... maybe a whole new app is in order instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An alternative action syntax is
>   available to dispatch the actions in
>   separate files, one file per action.
>   In this case, each action class
>   extends sfAction (instead of
>   sfActions) and is named
>   actionNameAction. The actual action
>   method is simply named execute.

```
class indexAction extends sfAction
{
  public function execute($request)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

[A Gentle Introduction to symfony - chapter 06: Inside the controller layer, subsection Alternative Action Class Syntax](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_sub_alternative_action_class_syntax)

Comment: Yeah, that's essentially the same thing I noted in my question, just some different syntax... I was looking for a way to group similar actions into their own files.

Comment: You're right in your comment: a new app is in order. Also take a look at [swCrossLinkApplicationPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/swCrossLinkApplicationPlugin).

Comment: Oh, nice!  Thanks for the link to the plugin.  This'll work great!